# How can I fix this react-native-navigation issue "80 packages are looking for funding run `npm fund` for details"?

Tags: react-native-navigation

I'm working in React Native CLI with Android Studio. I have tried **npm install** still not working and I don't have the permission yet to post images on stackoverflow.